# Using Node.Js Modules, how do I use an object function in the same module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I have an authentication module with methods I would like to use across the server. I would like to use the rndString() method in both the module itself and export it to use in other ways throughout the app. What am I doing wrong to cause this to not work?

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

let sha512 = (password, salt) => {
    let hash = crypto.createHmac('sha512', salt);
    hash.update(password);
    let value = hash.digest('hex');
    return {
        salt: salt,
        passwordHash: value
    }
};

module.exports = {
    rndString: (length) => {
        return crypto.randomBytes(Math.ceil(length/2))
            .toString('hex')
            .slice(0,length);
    },
    hashId: (id) => {
        let key  = crypto.createCipher('aes-128-cbc', 'kranky');
        let hash = key.update(id, 'utf8', 'hex');
        hash += key.final('hex');
        return hash;
    },
    saltPass: (userpassword) => {
        let salt         = this.rndString(16);
        let passwordData = sha512(userpassword, salt);
        return {
            hashValue: passwordData.passwordHash,
            salt: passwordData.salt
        }
    },
    userSalt: (userpassword, salt) => {
        let passwordData = sha512(userpassword, salt);
        return passwordData.passwordHash;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing the `rndString` function as `this.rndString` inside a function that is assigned to the object key here:

```
saltPass: (userpassword) => {
    let salt         = this.rndString(16);
    let passwordData = sha512(userpassword, salt);
```

In this case, `this` is actually referring to the function, rather than the object in which the function is nested. You can alternatively use ES6 method syntax to get the right context:

```
module.exports = {
  rndString(length) {
    return crypto.randomBytes(Math.ceil(length/2))
        .toString('hex')
        .slice(0,length);
  },
  hashId(id) {
    let key  = crypto.createCipher('aes-128-cbc', 'kranky');
    let hash = key.update(id, 'utf8', 'hex');
    hash += key.final('hex');
    return hash;
  },
  saltPass(userpassword) {
    let salt         = this.rndString(16);
    let passwordData = sha512(userpassword, salt);
    return {
        hashValue: passwordData.passwordHash,
        salt: passwordData.salt
    }
  },
  userSalt(userpassword, salt) {
    let passwordData = sha512(userpassword, salt);
    return passwordData.passwordHash;
  }
}
```

You can find good documentation here for object method shorthand: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions